# ring restriction of linear groups

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose that there is a group $G\subseteq\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ defined to be the group satisfying some equations on $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$(for example, given a nonsingular matrix $A$, $X=AXA^{-1}$, $X^*=AX^{-1}A^{-1}$, $X^{-1}=AX^tA^{-1}$, $\cdots$ for every $X\in G$). Now, let us define $G_R:=G\cap\text{GL}(n,R)$, where $R\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is an integral domain(e.g., $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, $\cdots$). Is there a general method to find properties(a (finite/infinite) set of generators, some normal subgroups, the center, $\cdots$) of $G_R$ from $G$?

Comment: Not that I know of. Already I think it's difficult to say things about groups of the form $\text{GL}_2(\mathcal{O}_K)$ where $K$ is a number field (e.g. to give generators). Even the problem of understanding $\text{GL}_1(\mathcal{O}_K)$ is nontrivial (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_unit_theorem). For a useful keyword try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_group.